# HTMLUnit and AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, seo, htmlunit

So I'm trying to do parsing of a javascript generated resource on the server side for SEO optimization. I'm following the example of using **HTMLUnit** on a java based server that google provides [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot).

We're currently hosted using app-engine but I'm finding when calling

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
```

I always receive this exception, anyone have any ideas:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.httpclient.HtmlUnitDomainHandler
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.httpclient.HtmlUnitBrowserCompatCookieSpec.<init>(HtmlUnitBrowserCompatCookieSpec.java:101)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.CookieManager.<init>(CookieManager.java:56)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<init>(WebClient.java:141)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<init>(WebClient.java:202)
    at filters.CrawlServlet.doFilter(CrawlServlet.java:38)
```

Comment: What HtmlUnit version do you use? There is no 101 line in HtmlUnitBrowserCompatCookieSpec in 2.16

Comment: My fault, there is line 101, can you post a small test case.

Answer (score 3):

I tested with HtmlUnit 2.16 and AppEngine and it works [here](http://1-dot-anhtmlunit.appspot.com/guestbook).

With a sample project, copying the 2.16 jars to war/WEB-INF/lib, and having:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GuestbookServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
            final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
            resp.getWriter().println(page.getTitleText());           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be a `httpclient` version dependency problem, for `HTMLUnit 2.16` you should use `httpclient 4.4.1`